# how to pass value from href link to ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to call `ajax function` ...and send value......
by `href link`...
but without passing by `url`.....
I need to print content ....and that content come's form database...
So i'm using  ajax..........

### my ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    show_customize_image = function () {
        alert('test');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_url_store,
            data: {
                action: 'store',
                views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct())
            },

            success: function (data) {
                if (parseInt(data) > 0) {
                    $("#cart_pd").submit();

                }

            },
            error: function () {
                //alert('some error has occured...');
            },
            start: function () {
                //alert('ajax has been started...');    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

### my html

```
<td class="center">
    < a href="javascript:;" onclick="show_customize_image('<?php echo $pageVal['customers_id'];?>');">Delete
        < /a>
</td>
```

Comment: What is the question man! What is not working and what have you tried?

Comment: What is the page showing? Have you included the jquery library?

Comment: the wording of this question..... could be better.... and there is no need.... for many `period`s.... between parts of the sentence....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Col</th>
    <th>Col</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td class="center"> <a href="javascript:void();" class="tdelete" data="<?php echo $pageVal['customers_id'];?>">Delete</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".tdelete").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var varFromPhp = $(this).attr("data"));
    //ajax request....    
});
```

});

[feedly](http://jsfiddle.net/mePLX/)

Comment: According to W3C specs, the correct HTML 5 way would be to use [custom data- attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), e.g. data-customerid